# Increase hitbox size of textbox to show context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a multiline textbox in which the right click context menu only appears if you right click on a line which contains text. I would like to expand the hitbox so that right clicking anywhere within the textbox will show the default context menu.

In the image below, I have highlighted the region in which the right click context menu works.

[image: wpf multiline textbox]

Here is the XAML for the textbox:

```
<TextBox Margin="3" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
     Cursor="IBeam"
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
     AcceptsTab="True" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
     IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
     Text="{Binding CONFIDENTIAL}"
     adonisExtensions:WatermarkExtension.Watermark="CONFIDENTIAL"
     />
```

Please let me know if there is additional information I can provide.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Do you mean the copy, paste, cut context menu? It will usually open when clicking anywhere inside the TextBox (it must in order to enable text pasting). You are binding the IsReadOnly property. Maybe your TextBox is in read-only mode? In this case it won't respond to right clicks inside the TextBox as you are not allowed to paste content. Still clicking e.g. selected text to copy it should also always work.

Comment: Yes the default copy. paste, cut context menu. It does not open when clicking anywhere inside the TextBox. In the example above, it only works when right clicking the first line. If I were to right click anywhere else, the context menu will not show. In the example, the textbox is not in read-only mode.

Please let me know how I can be more specific, I'm not sure what further information I can provide.